# Return different serializer after create() in CreateAPIView in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using **Django 2.2** and **Django REST Framework**.

I have to serializers for the same model.

```
class OrderListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    plan = PlanBaseSerializer(read_only=True, many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = [
            'id', 'name', 'plan', 'pricing',
            'created', 'completed',
        ]


class OrderCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    plan_pricing = serializers.IntegerField(required=True, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = [
            'plan_pricing'
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        plan_pricing_ = validated_data.pop('plan_pricing', None)
        try:
            plan_pricing = PlanPricing.objects.get(pk=plan_pricing_)
        except PlanPricing.DoesNotExists:
            raise ValidationError('Plan pricing not available')

        validated_data['plan'] = plan_pricing.plan
        validated_data['amount'] = plan_pricing.price

        return super().create(validated_data)
```

`OrderListSerializer` serializer is used for listing orders or order detail view and `OrderCreateSerializer` is used for creating a new order instance.

The view is

```
class CreateOrderView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = OrderCreateSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

This is working fine as the order object is creating as expected. But the returned value contains no data.

I want to use `OrderListSerializer` to render saved order details after creating the order.

**How to change the serializer class after creating the object?**

Also, I have to trigger a signal after the object has been successfully created. **What is the best place to trigger a signal?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Change **`CreateOrderView`** as below,

```
class CreateOrderView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = OrderCreateSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        instance = self.perform_create(serializer)
        instance_serializer = OrderListSerializer(instance)
        return Response(instance_serializer.data)
```

**`serializer.save()`** returns the instance that just created or updated. So we use that istance to pass to the `OrderListSerializer` and returning the corresponding response.

Answer (score 1):

You could overwrite `create()`, and return whatever you want:

```
from rest_framework import response, status
(...)
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return response.Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can use here. First,

```
class CreateOrderView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = OrderCreateSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

    def list(self, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer_class = OrderListSerializer
        serializer = serializer_class(self.get_queryset())
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

The alternative would be a conditional if statement, where

```
if self.request.method=='POST':
   self.serializer_class = OrderCreateSerializer
elif self.request.method=='GET':
   self.serializer_class = OrderListSerializer
```